# Measure transfer time in OpenCL only for a part of the data

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to measure the time taken for transferring a part of the data (the content of one of the buffers) to the GPU.

I tried to use this:

```
cl_command_queue queueGPU = clCreateCommandQueue(GPUcontext, GPUdeviceIds[0], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &error);

cl_event transfer1;
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queueGPU, data, CL_TRUE, 0, dataSize, loadedData, 0, nullptr, &transfer1);
clWaitForEvents(1, &transfer1);

cl_event transfer2;
clEnqueueWriteBuffer (queueGPU, indices, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * queryCount, inputData, 0, nullptr, &transfer2);
clWaitForEvents(1, &transfer2);
unsigned long start = 0;
unsigned long end = 0;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(transfer2, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof (cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(transfer2, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof (cl_ulong), &end, NULL);
unsigned long transferTime = end - start;
```

But it returns exactly the same time as the time for transferring all the data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How much time for other buffer and this buffer separately?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik that's what I'm trying to find out, yes. Actually, I need the time for the second one only.

Comment: What do you get for now? How do you know exactly same with all data?

Comment: I get ~0.022 milliseconds (of course not exactly the same number every time, but very close, since I do 100 repetitions).
To measure the transfer time for all data I use one event for writing both buffers and then get the time.

Comment: Are you sure its in "milliseconds"?  Then its 22 microseconds. In 22 microseconds, pci-e would transfer only 40-160 kB data, maybe even less(5-10 kB) if not optimized. How large is that buffer in bytes? What happens if you double the size of it? Time doubles too?

Comment: The size of the data is small (~400 kB), so maybe that's the problem. When I double the size, the transfer takes 0.041ms.
I just tested it on a bigger batch (~200 MB) and got different results (36.57ms for all data and 22.59 for the second part only).

Comment: 9GB/s for just 400kB data is good. Maybe time measurement error is too big for 20 microseconds because of api overhead and host synchronization.

Comment: I think I found the problem: I used the same event to measure the time for all data, which gave me the time only for one of the buffers. Below I posted the fixed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the time was the same because every clEnqueueWriteBuffer requires its own event, and I measured the time for all data using the same event. Which gave me the time for only one of the buffers.

This should work fine:

```
// Transfer time for both buffers

cl_event transfer1;
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queueGPU, data, CL_TRUE, 0, dataSize, loadedData, 0, nullptr, &transfer1);
clWaitForEvents(1, &transfer1);
unsigned long start = 0;
unsigned long end = 0;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(transfer1, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof (cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(transfer1, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof (cl_ulong), &end, NULL);
unsigned long transferTime1 = end - start;

cl_event transfer2;
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queueGPU, indices, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * queryCount, inputData, 0, nullptr, &transfer2);
clWaitForEvents(1, &transfer2);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(transfer2, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof (cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(transfer2, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof (cl_ulong), &end, NULL);
unsigned long transferTime = end - start + transferTime1;
```